# Navigate to Activity when ANR occurs

Tags: android

Is it possible to navigate to a custom activity when ANR happens?

For example it is possible to catch a crash in Application class and navigate to a custom activity by using this code snippet:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { thread, throwable ->
    applicationContext.startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MyCrashActivity::class.java))
}
```

Wondering if there is something close to this example with ANRs too.

Comment: You might possibly log it somewhere but by the nature of what ANR is - UI thread is locked in some heavy computing work or deadlocked so it is not responing - you can't.

Comment: Logging ANR is quite simple by using Play Console, Firebase Crashlytics or manual logging with [ApplicationExitInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo). Was wondering if it would be possible to have any background thread that awaits ANR trigger and then launches an activity by killing ANR activity.